# Response from scraping be encoded

Tags: python, scrape

I'm a newbie in coding and looking for a way to scrape a bank's exchange rate data in python.
I found some banks they present the exchange-rate in an action table (i guess, it's java) so the exchange rate will be show immediately after query by date.

In this case it's this url = https://hdbank.com.vn/en/personal/cong-cu/exchange-rate

I checked Network and catch the response after query by date as below:

Network inspect - Firefox:

[image: Network inspect - Firefox]

But the respond is not in `html/json` or some thing like that. how can i get it in html so I can extract the table from it?

the table in html I want to extract:

[image: the table in html i want to extract]

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Look into [`scrapy`](https://scrapy.org) and/or [`beautifulsoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: You'll need to scrape the html response for the information you are after. This html scraping is VERY common. Check out those two links by @wkl.

Comment: At the first glance I thought/hoped it was some BASE64 encoded JSON or something ... but it seems the data is somehow also encrypted (probably to protect from guys like you :D ) ... at this point you'll have to either look into some other scraping technique that "scraps" the things that shows in a browser or reverse-engineer the code in the page in order to understand how it decodes that data.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i can extract the data from html, but the problem here is, the responds is not in HTML. (i mean the response after i query by date).

Comment: @LohmarASHAR Yup i also think the response data have been encrypted. but it doesn't seem very logic since these information is publish.

i can get the response in html by request directly to the website-url. But in this way, i can not query by date.

Comment: oh ... you haven't tried scrapping lists of open proxies yet ... :D. The idea is to get you to make a "full hit" (or at least as close as possible) on the page and not give you a "free API"; if they get their hit counter up and/or manage to "show" some ads they might be ok with you scrapping their content.